# Rails3: Upon Devise log in, route to document identified in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-routing

My Rails3 app uses Devise for authentication.

Just after clicking the "log in" button, I want each user to be routed to a given document (id of this document is stored in database, changes often).

Is there a best-practice to handle this in Rails3?

I see two options:

1. Create a single huge page, which checks the database and renders the appropriate document accordingly.
2. In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, check the database and route accordingly to the right document.

Which is best? Any smarter idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the after_sign_in_path_for hook in your login controller (or application controller) to be something like:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
    #Whatever url you need to here
  else
    super
  end
end
```

and that should do the trick.

Comment: I just placed this code in my `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and replaced the *whatever url* line with *"http://0.0.0.0:3000/monkeys/2/edit?locale=ja"* Unfortunately, even after restarting the rails server, users are directed to *http://0.0.0.0:3000/*

Comment: That is odd, since this what I do and it works. Can you confirm that your code is actually reaching the url line?

Comment: This method is never reached indeed! I added a debug line just at the beginning of the `after_sign_in_path_for` method, and it never gets printed. I had added your method inside `class ApplicationController`, is it not the right place?

Comment: I am always directed to the root page defined in `routes.rb`, for instance `root :to => "monkeys#new"`

Comment: The default is the root path. The ApplicationController is the place to put this. I don't think it can be a private method since it is being called from a subclass, so make sure that it is a protected (or I guess public) method.
Documentation here says though it should work. I'm confused why it is not. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L176